# Issue while converting object type to int

Tags: python, dataframe, object, type-conversion, integer

I have a lengthy python code in which I was changing the data types of few of the columns from object to int or float using below method

```
df['a'] = df['a'].astype('int')
df['b'] = df['b'].astype('int')
```

However I got below error after this conversion

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'method'
```

Has anybody came across this error before?? Please help.

Comment: Try to run `type(df['b'])`. Is it an Int? It sounds like you left it as a method.

Comment: What's in that column? It sounds like a previous operation was incorrect.

Comment: I guess this is wrong by the way. The type will be a pandas Series. You would have to do: `df['b'].dtype` instead.

Comment: Df['b'] is object data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got that error because that column has at least one python `method` object in it. Its likely the whole column is filled with a method. Now I have to speculate because you haven't given us enough information, but this is easy to do accidently if you misapply a `ufunc` by neglecting to call it.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1],[-2],[3]], columns=['a'])
>>> df['a'] = df['a'].abs    # BUG: Fills column with `method` object
>>> df['a'] = df['a'].astype('int')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5881, in astype
    new_data = self._data.astype(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 581, in astype
    return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 438, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 559, in astype
    return self._astype(dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors, values=values, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 643, in _astype
    values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py", line 711, in astype_nansafe
    return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 547, in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'method'
```

You need to look at the last thing you did to that column and see if it accidentally filled the column with a method object. If so, add those cowboy legs `()`.

```
df['a'] = df['a'].abs()
```

Comment: Hi @tdelaney: Thanks for the swift response. I have created clusters and uploaded the minimum and maximum value corresponding a cluster in that column. As you asked to add ()... I would like to ask should I add () in conversion statment like .astype(int())....If so, then I again encountered an error that can't interpret '0' asdata type. I have 0 as one of the value in the column

Comment: The badness happened before the `astype` call. `astype` found method objects in the column and you have to figure out how they got there. Its a good bet that the thing you did to that column just before the stuff you show us is the problem. In my example, it would be `df['a'] = df['a'].abs()`

Comment: Unfortunately it is again giving an error : bad operand type for abs(): method ()

Comment: I was just using `abs` as an example. Since I don't have your code I can't really guess which function it is. In any case, if you added the parens to whatever function you are using, and then got this error, that just means you've discovered another bug. You have to figure out why *that* function is failing.

Comment: But lets be clear, I'm not suggesting that you do `df['a'] = df['a'].abs().astype('int')`. I'm suggesting that you look at the code *above* these lines that put the `method` object in the column in the first place. Since you haven't shown us that code, we can only speculate what it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed response...I have missed () in my min and max values and those were causing the issue...This also fixed a lot of other issues in my code...Really appreciated